# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: arguments[0].click is not a function using execute_script() in Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've check the docs and other forums I haven't found a concrete answer. please find below the code snippet.

```
def click_hamburger_menu(self):
    _hamburger_menu_ = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(
                                EC.visibility_of_element_located((
                                By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg' and @class='site-header__nav-trigger']")))
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", _hamburger_menu_)
```

Error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: arguments[0].click is not a function
```

Comment: The `execute_script` function is apparently looking for a function as its first parameter. What you're passing in is not a function. What exactly are you expecting that call to do?

Comment: Are you sure you ran the code you posted? The code you posted looks fine. My guess is that you ran `arguments[0].click` (without the `()`s).

Comment: Ironically it ran well when I removed the () , still questioning why

Answer (score -1):

Seems you were pretty close. You need to add a **`;`** after the `click()` method.

So effectively the line of code:

```
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", _hamburger_menu_)
```

will be:

```
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", _hamburger_menu_)
```

Comment: `;` isn't required. I just ran it with and without and both worked.